# How to return an array of integers using C# Interop?

Tags: c#, arrays, interop

I'm trying to return an array of integers and can't get it to work...

Below id my code that has the following error on `return array`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int'

```
  public int getIndexes(int num) 
    {
        var wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
        var wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];


        Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
        if (num == 0) sheet = wsEvars;

        if (num != 2)
        {
            var rng = (Excel.Range)sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[3, 2], sheet.Cells[3, 27]];
            var wsValues = rng.Cells.Value;
            int scopeIndex = 0;
            int methodIndex = 0;
            int delimiterIndex = 0;
            int formatIndex = 0;
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var head in wsValues)
            {
                if (head == "*Scope")
                    scopeIndex = count + 1;
                if (head == "Set Method")
                    methodIndex = count + 1;
                if (head == "Delimiter")
                    delimiterIndex = count + 1;
                if (head == "Format")
                    formatIndex = count + 1;
            }
            int[] array = new int[]{scopeIndex, methodIndex, delimiterIndex, formatIndex};
            return array;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The type of your method is `int` but you are trying to return an array of integers. So change the type of your method to `int[]` also.

Comment: Tried, but I get the following error in addition to previous `ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.getIndexes(int)': not all code paths return a value`

Comment: Don't you think this is a wonderfully explicit error message??

Comment: Because the return statement is inside the second if block. You have to return something for the other cases.

Comment: "not all code paths return a value" - Because your only return statement is inside an IF conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your method is returning an `int` and not an `int[]` as you want. Also, yo are doing the return inside the `if` block, and that won´t ensure that the `return` will be hit because that will only happen if the condition is true. What about if the condition is false? You are not returning anything in that case. Get the `return` out of the block:

```
public int[] getIndexes(int num) 
{
    int[] array = null;
    var wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    var wsEvars = wb.Sheets["Evars"];


    Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
    if (num == 0) sheet = wsEvars;

    if (num != 2)
    {
        var rng = (Excel.Range)sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[3, 2], sheet.Cells[3, 27]];
        var wsValues = rng.Cells.Value;
        int scopeIndex = 0;
        int methodIndex = 0;
        int delimiterIndex = 0;
        int formatIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var head in wsValues)
        {
            if (head == "*Scope")
                scopeIndex = count + 1;
            if (head == "Set Method")
                methodIndex = count + 1;
            if (head == "Delimiter")
                delimiterIndex = count + 1;
            if (head == "Format")
                formatIndex = count + 1;
        }
        array = new int[]{scopeIndex, methodIndex, delimiterIndex, formatIndex};
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: I will handle the case when the condition is false to return other values. After changing the code I get: `Use of unassigned local variable 'array'
`

Comment: do int[] array = null;